# Running out of memory in this CoreData (Objective C) code segment

Tags: objective-c

I wrote this method to test a CoreData backing store. While running the test method,
I am running out of memory. I have 100 elements in the inner loop and 10
records in the outer loop. I am testing this on an iPad (actual device).

```
-(void) uploadTestHubData: (NSInteger) hubs entriesPerHub: (NSInteger) elems
{
    CoreDataWrapper *cdw = [CoreDataWrapper getInstance:@"/Documents/journaldata0.sqlite"];
[self loadTestImages];

for (int i = 0; i < hubs; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Uploading hub - %d", i);

    Hub *newhub = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Hub" inManagedObjectContext:cdw.context];
    newhub.Title = @"Changed ... Hub Title";
    newhub.Last_Update = [NSDate date];
    newhub.Create_Date = [NSDate date];
    newhub.Type = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    newhub.Description = @"This is a test hub. I am just testing the hub structure.";

    for (int j = 0; j < elems; j++) {
        HubBasicElement *helem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"HubBasicElement" inManagedObjectContext:cdw.context];
        helem.CoverArt = UIImagePNGRepresentation([self getRandomImage]);
        helem.Create_Date = [NSDate date];
        helem.Title = @"Title of Clipped Page";
        helem.ElementType = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        helem.Source_URL = @"Some web URL";
        [newhub addChildrenObject:helem];
        [cdw commitCoreData];
    }
}       
NSLog(@"Finished uploading the test data ....");
}
```

Comment: at first glance, it looks like you are creating about 1000 autoreleased Core Data objects as well as a number of autoreleased NSNumbers and NSDate objects.  If you are having memory issues, you might want to consider adding an NSAutoreleasePool wrapped around your inner for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did that already! I get the following error message. *** -[NSAutoreleasePool drain]: This pool has already been drained,....

Comment: Try alloc/init before the outer loop, then drain and alloc/init another instance after u exit the inner loop.